# OSX signing issue with self-patching application bundle

Tags: macos, codesign, self-updating

I am building a game that needs to update itself to the latest version every time it's run, for bug fixes and multiplayer compatibility.  I have set up an application bundle that checks the servers for a new version, and if it exists, it downloads it and extracts it to the bundle.  Then, it will run the game's executable.  After signing this, the patcher works perfectly.  The game, however, seems to lack write privileges and can't save keybindings or progress.  When I try to sign it with this command:

codesign -f -i "[myID]" myapplication.app/ --deep --force --verbose

I get this error message:

myapplication.app: code object is not signed at all
In subcomponent: /Users/Lat/Desktop/myapplication.app/Contents/MacOS/ExampleGame
In architecture: x86_64

It is a project requirement that this game be one bundle that you run and it takes care of everything.  How can I sign both executables?

Presumably, I would need to resign the whole thing whenever the game exe patches.